# Updation to Global Picklist Value Set through Tooling API makes the existing values deactivated state in salesforce

Tags: apex, global-picklist

I am trying to update my salesforce global pick set values using Tooling API for my learning practice. When I am using tooling API end point to update global pick list values, updation is working properly with new value. But existing values are going to deactivated state. When I am checking pick list values after updation it showing button to activate.

I used following code to update my existing global pick set value,

And when I checks in my setup, it showing the previous values got deactivated and activated only the new added value. which means existing values getting deactivates after adding new values,

So Why the previous values in pick list goes deactivates state? Please anyone guide me to resolve this issue where I went in wrong? And please correct me that the updation need any more attribute to set to not to happen like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the standard behavior with picklists. When you perform a deployment against the picklist, the value set is updated to match the deployed picklist values, and any values existing in the org that are *not* present in the deployment are deactivated.

There is no way to change this behavior or to address individual picklist value set entries.

Instead, you must retrieve the picklist value set first, modify it to add the entries you desire, and then deploy the *entire* value set back into the org.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When you say modify entries and  deploy entire value set back to org means again use the same POST request? I did not understood

Comment: No, you should leave it as PATCH. First, you need to retrieve existing values from your global picklist. Then there will be something like: ```{"Metadata":{"customValue":[{"label":"Transgender","isActive":true,"valueName":"Transgender"},{"label":"Female","isActive":true,"valueName":"Female"},{"label":"Male","isActive":true,"valueName":"Male"}],"masterLabel":"Gender"},"FullName":"Gender"}``` in your `fieldDef` variable.